# Is it ok to add a table years in a Relational DataBase?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

How can i explain my coworker that this is unnecessary complexity and redundant data?

[Database diagram picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSgk4.png)

He wants to have a table of years because many tables have the year value, and he also want to have relation table with names and years, i just want to make sure this is not a good practice even if 2NF say so...

Comment: This could be a question for the [dba site of the network](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Is each year an "entity" you need to manage in your application?

Answer these questions:

- Does the year have attributes?
- Does it need to be closed? (does it change state?)
- Do you need to record who closed it, when, under which reason?
- Can it be reopened or something? (is there a related workflow?)

If you answer "no" to these questions (and other ones), then it's not an entity.

If you answer "yes" then it is. If it is, then you probably need an extra table with attributes and primary keys; other tables will have foreign keys to it.

But the final answer is... it depends on the business model.

Answer (score 0):

Would you make a table of integers?  I think not.

Would you make a table for dates?  Well, there is an argument for this.  Suppose you want to list all the days in a month, even the days for which there is no data.  In *this* situation, a `LEFT JOIN` with the date table provides a way to create a 'report' with zeros for missing data.

There is a datatype called `YEAR` that works perfectly well.  You probably do not have any missing years?

(A Mantra:  Normalize, but don't over-normalize.)